# Using Julia JavaCall with Java DecimalFormat (à la MATLAB)

Tags: java, matlab, julia

I don't know java and can't get `JavaCall.jl` to work with `java.text.DecimalFormat`. In MATLAB this is very simple -- just check out this [link](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/formatting-numbers).

Reading the `JavaCall.jl` [documentation](http://juliainterop.github.io/JavaCall.jl/), I tried replicating the provided example with `DecimalFormat` and got this far:

```julia
julia>using JavaCall
julia>JavaCall.init(["-Xmx128M"])
julia>jdf = @jimport  java.text.DecimalFormat
```

After that, I got a bunch of errors. (bear in mind: I absolutely have no clue as to how Java works?)

Please help!

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Do you only need to format some numbers?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question whether you're looking to know more about `JavaCall.jl` or just to use some comma separated formatting.
If the latter, then you can use the `Formatting.jl` package: https://github.com/JuliaIO/Formatting.jl

```
julia> using Formatting

julia> sprintf1("%'.02f", 123456789)
"123,456,789.00"
```

And then you don't need any Java.

This package also has a bunch of other formatting options.